# Script for changing monitor refresh rate when fullscreen on a specific website.

Tags: scripting, video, monitors, browser, adobe-flash

### Premise

I recently discovered this website where I can watch legal streaming of plenty of animes. They use a flash player and the CEO said that, for legal reasons, they can't use a HTML5 player.

### The issue

The flash player causes screen tearing. It's obviously very annoying and I really would like to find a solution.

### Details

**Browser**: Firefox. I tested it on Chrome and Opera and it works fine, but often it freezes and I have to reload the page.

**OS**: ArchLinux.

**Monitor**: Asus VE247H @60Hz

**Flash version installed**: 11.2

**GPU**: nVidia 770 w/ nVidia 340.76 drivers.

### My idea

I was thinking about a scripts that changes the monitor refresh rate when I'm full screen on that website. In this way I'd not encounter tearing due to the difference of the refresh rate.

Any other idea is appreciated.

Comment: Another idea: checkout `youtube-dl` + vlc. Youtube-dl, besides youtube, it has grown support for many other sites.

Comment: Well, basically to change rate you have to use `xrandr --rate`. Unfortunately the only thing that knows when you're in specific web site is the browser — and I've no idea how to force it to run an application.

Comment: Yes, I knew about xrandr. I hope someone is skilled enough to write a script for my problem, because I am not hehe.

Comment: Does it really solve your problem to change the refresh rate of the desktop?  Have you ever tested with that setting?

Comment: @yaegashi you're completely right, I haven't tested it with a different refresh rate. I'll edit the original post after trying. Thanks for the comment.